# How do I set a boolean value atomically in Delphi?

Tags: delphi

AtomicExchange requires an Integer or NativeInt variable, but how could I use it (or something similar) to set a boolean value in a thread-safe way - or is there any need for it?

Comment: It depends what you are trying to do. If you want to toggle the value, then you need one of the AtomicXXX functions, and you need to use a 32 bit boolean. But if you just want to set the value to a specific value, without a read, then you can do that directly using plain assignment.

Comment: A `Boolean` is a single byte. For simple read-only and write-only operations, just access the variable directly and let the system handle atomic access for you, there is no need to access a `Boolean` using atomic APIs manually.  It is only when you need to perform multiple operations together (read-then-write, write-then-read) that you need to coordinate atomic access to ensure the integrity of the value. However, there are no atomic APIs for single-byte data types. You can just use a synchronization object instead, like a `TCriticalSection`, `TMutex`, `TMREWSync`, etc

Comment: @Remy more efficient to use atomic ops on a 32 bit type

Comment: OK, thanks. I just want to ensure that the value is changed safefy, in case several remote clients try to do that from different threads. So I guess I can just trust the byte value to be safe as it is. So I was uncertain the size of Boolean, but since it's just byte, it's fine.

Answer (score 5):

A Delphi `Boolean` is a byte value and cannot be used with the Atomic API's as they operate on 32bit values.

You could use a `BOOL` instead which is a 32bit boolean like this:

```
var
  b: bool;
begin
  b := False;

  // true
  AtomicIncrement(Integer(b));

  // false
  AtomicDecrement(Integer(b));
```

However incrementing is a bit dangerous as incrementing it twice (similar to assigning True twice) and decrementing it once means the value is > 0 and thus still `True`.

An alternative might be this:

```
  // false
  AtomicExchange(Integer(b), Integer(False));

  // true
  AtomicExchange(Integer(b), Integer(True));
```